# Unable to access UI for kubeflow

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow, microk8s

I have installed Kubeflow onto Ubuntu 18.04 running on microk8s.  To do this I followed the instructions on https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/started/getting-started/.

Everything seems to be running correctly:

```
steven@linux:~/my-kf$ microk8s.kubectl  -n kubeflow get all
NAME                                                          READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
pod/ambassador-b4d9cdb8-79km4                                 1/1     Running            3          4d20h
pod/ambassador-b4d9cdb8-drs95                                 1/1     Running            3          4d20h
pod/ambassador-b4d9cdb8-gkn6w                                 1/1     Running            3          4d20h
pod/argo-ui-6d6658d8f7-4kv7x                                  1/1     Running            2          4d20h
```

I set up port-forwarding:

```
steven@linux:~/my-kf$ microk8s.kubectl port-forward svc/ambassador -n kubeflow 9999:80
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:9999 -> 80
Forwarding from [::1]:9999 -> 80
```

And then try to access the UI by pointing a web browser at

```
http://127.0.0.1:9999/
```

however, I just get the following in the browser

```
no healthy upstream
```

I get the log for the ambassador service using

```
steven@linux:~$ microk8s.kubectl -n kubeflow logs svc/ambassador
```

and all I can see is

```
 ACCESS [2019-02-07T06:39:38.623Z] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 UH 0 19 0 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0" "3b346da8-be7b-43fa-9b62-6db0a449a8f3" "127.0.0.1:9999" "-"
```

This is quite frustrating - any help in being able to access the Kubeflow cluster would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's related to Ambassador issue: resourceVersion: Invalid value [here](https://github.com/datawire/ambassador/issues/928)

Upgrade Ambassador version to 0.50.0 can solve this.

> microk8s.kubectl -n kubeflow edit deployment ambassador